# ArrayList operation

Tags: java, arraylist

This a very short and direct question, but I haven't been able to find an answer to it.
Consider the following situation.

```
ArrayList<A> listOne, listTwo;
listOne = new ArrayList<A>();
listTwo = listOne;
```

My question is what happens to `listTwo`. From a C "nativespeaker" standpoint, is only the pointer copied and no other operations are performed, or is the list replicated in a new memory area. My objective with this code is the following:

```
ArrayList<A> listOne, listTwo, auxList;
//listOne and listTwo have been initialized and filled somewhere else.

public void method( int opType ){
    if( opType == 0)
        auxList = listOne; //Set pointer, not copy list;
    else
        auxList = listTwo; //Set pointer, not copy list;

    ....
}
```

Comment: Note that your snippet in `method` can be conveniently expressed as `auxList = opType == 0 ? listOne : listTwo;`.

Comment: Will that change affect the performance in a perceivable way?

Comment: No, it won't. But it's slightly less error prone, since it's clear that `auxList` is getting assigned regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] is only the pointer copied and no other operations are performed, or is the list replicated in a new memory area.

The reference contained in `listOne` is copied into `listTwo`.

The list is not replicated. There will only be one list around.

Comment: but what happens when you change listone? Does listtwo also change? Dont think so....

Comment: @MaVRoSCy, no, if you change `listOne` (i.e. store another reference in that variable) nothing happens to the value stored in `listTwo`. If you change the list that `listOne` refers to, then the list that `listTwo` refers to changes as well (since they refer to the same list).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is just the reference to the `List` object that is copied. From a C standpoint it is the equivalent to doing this:

```
list *list_one, list_two;
list_one = malloc(sizeof(list));
list_two = list_one;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is only 1 list. This can be seen by the fact that there is only one `new` keyword creating a list. Both the `listOne` and `listTwo` variables point to the same `ArrayList` object.

Answer (score 2):

listTwo will have the reference to listOne, the list itself wont be copied.
If you want to copy listOne to a new object you can use clone() or a copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Both variables will point to the same list object, cf:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> listOne, listTwo;
    listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    listTwo = listOne;
    System.out.println(listOne == listTwo);
    listOne.add("foo");
    System.out.println(listOne == listTwo);
    System.out.println(listOne);
    System.out.println(listTwo);
    listTwo.add("bar");
    System.out.println(listOne == listTwo);
    System.out.println(listOne);
    System.out.println(listTwo);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
[foo]
[foo]
true
[foo, bar]
[foo, bar]
```

Note that in java the `==` operator returns `true` if both sides refer to the same object.